# Persistent AttributeError ('TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out') even after updating scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, attributeerror

I was attempting to retrieve the tfidf matrix shape and the feature names with the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Amanda\Desktop\testing.xlsx')
fe = Tfidf()
X = fe.fit_transform(my_data['abstract'])
print(X.shape)
print(fe._model)
print(fe.get_feature_names_out())
```

I got the following output and AttributeError:

```
(9, 680)
TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
AttributeError: 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out'
```

Online answers pointed out the problem to be an outdated version of scikit-learn. They recommended updating the package. However, I was still unable to rectify the AttributeError. I tried variations of the commands to no avail.

> pip install -U scikit-learn

> python -m pip install --upgrade --user scikit-learn

> conda install scikit-learn